# Sencha touch json saving in raw instead of data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch

I have the following JSON

> {"pic":[{"id":"10","title":"Perro","descripcion":"Un lindo perrito","puntos":"300","ext":"jpeg","image_time":"2014-07-28 03:58:31","data":"","URL":"pug.jpeg"},{"id":"12","title":"Pugs","descripcion":"\u00danete a la fuerza","puntos":"123","ext":"jpeg","image_time":"2014-07-30 07:05:42","data":"","URL":"image.jpg"},{"id":"14","title":"burro","descripcion":"lindo burro","puntos":"678","ext":"png","image_time":"2014-07-30 16:25:44","data":"","URL":"1456105_475563429219279_7985916_n.png"}]}

And the following model:

```
Ext.define('hptest2.model.pic', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields: [
            {name: 'id',   type: 'int'},
            {name: 'URL',   type: 'String'},
            {name: 'puntos',   type: 'int'}, 
            {name: 'title',   type: 'String'},
            {name: 'descripcion',   type: 'String'},
            {name: 'data',   type: 'String'},
            {name: 'ext',   type: 'String'},
            {name: 'image_time',   type: 'String'},
        ]
    }
});
```

And its store:

```
Ext.define('hptest2.store.pic', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'hptest2.model.pic',

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data/pic.php'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'pic'
        }

    }
});
```

But when I use a tpl on a view... I just can't access the data from the store

View:

```
{
    title: 'Promociones',
    iconCls: 'star',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            store : 'pic',
            tpl:new Ext.XTemplate('<div>{URL} with {puntos}</div>'),                              
         }
    ]
}
```

The data is stored in raw but not in data

At console with Ext.getStore('pic') in data -> all -> data ... all my columns from my model appear as follow:

```
data: Object
    URL: null
    data: null
    descripcion: null
    ext: null
    id: "ext-record-6"
    image_time: null
    puntos: null
    title: null
```

but in data -> all -> data -> raw I am able to visualise all data that I wished I could access through my view

```
pic: Array[3]
    0: Object
        URL: "pug.jpeg"
        data: ""
        descripcion: "Un lindo perrito"
        ext: "jpeg"
        id: "10"
        image_time: "2014-07-28 03:58:31"
        puntos: "300"
        title: "Perro"
        __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    2: Object
```